# How to get formatted address NSString from AddressDictionary?

Tags: ios, addressbook, clgeocoder

Trying to get formatted address from AddressDictionary, that I got from CLGeocoder.
Used following code with no result:

```
subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:[[addressDict objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Also tried:

```
subtitle = [[[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] formattedAddressFromDictionary:placemark.addressDictionary] string];
```

but this code seems working on Mac OS X only.

Compiler asks about ABAdressBook, but I have both header files imported.

```
#import <AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The documentation for the `addressDictionary` property says:

> You can format the contents of this dictionary to get a full address
>   string as opposed to building the address yourself. To format the
>   dictionary, use the ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary function as
>   described in Address Book UI Functions Reference.

So add and import the `AddressBookUI` framework and try:

```
subtitle = 
    ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placemark.addressDictionary, NO);
```

Comment: This is the right method to use... However it does not always provide a complete address. For instance looking up "wall street" with CLGeocoder will return a placemark and calling ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary on the placemark dictionary will return "New York, NY, United Stated"... And "Wall Street" is nowhere to be found.

Comment: This method also adds weird ascii characters, last checked in iOS8

Comment: fyi - ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary has been deprecated in iOS 9.0

Comment: ```addressDictionary``` is deprecated in iOS 11.

Answer (score 24):

After doing some digging under iOS 6.1 I found out that the CLPlacemark address dictionary contains a pre-formatted address:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:37.3175 longitude:-122.041944];
[[[CLGeocoder alloc]init] reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
    NSArray *lines = placemark.addressDictionary[ @"FormattedAddressLines"];
    NSString *addressString = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"Address: %@", addressString);
}];
```

I couldn't yet find documentation about this, but it works for all the addresses that I tested.

Comment: It's the same as in question.

Comment: Yes, but you said it was NOT working. My tests on all my devices and in the simulator show that it is actually working. At least with the most recent iOS versions.

Comment: this is a good answer but in order for me to get the FULL address I had to use this instead `NSString *addressString = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@", "];`

Comment: @DigitalChild you can join the lines by any string. I guess that you didn't see the full address because I used the new line character.

Comment: When I search for "Apple" in Palo Alto, I get back two Apple Store results. Neither have the `"FormattedAddressLines"` key in its `addressDictionary`.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale how to you search for "Apple" in Palo Alto? Are you using the `CLGeocoder` class?

Comment: @Klass no, I'm using `MKLocalSearch`.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale ok, might be that `"FormattedAddressLines"` is only there after issuing a reverse geocoding call.

Answer (score 20):

As highlighted by Martyn Davis, `ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary` is deprecated in iOS 9.

You can use the functions below to convert the `addressDictionary` to the newer `CNMutablePostalAddress`, then use the `CNPostalAddressFormatter` to generate a localised string as long as you import the `Contacts` framework.

#### Swift 3.x

```
// Convert to the newer CNPostalAddress
func postalAddressFromAddressDictionary(_ addressdictionary: Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>) -> CNMutablePostalAddress {
   let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()

   address.street = addressdictionary["Street" as NSObject] as? String ?? ""
   address.state = addressdictionary["State" as NSObject] as? String ?? ""
   address.city = addressdictionary["City" as NSObject] as? String ?? ""
   address.country = addressdictionary["Country" as NSObject] as? String ?? ""
   address.postalCode = addressdictionary["ZIP" as NSObject] as? String ?? ""

   return address
}

// Create a localized address string from an Address Dictionary
func localizedStringForAddressDictionary(addressDictionary: Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>) -> String {
    return CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: postalAddressFromAddressDictionary(addressDictionary), style: .mailingAddress)
}
```

#### Swift 2.x

```
import Contacts

// Convert to the newer CNPostalAddress
func postalAddressFromAddressDictionary(addressdictionary: Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>) -> CNMutablePostalAddress {

    let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()

    address.street = addressdictionary["Street"] as? String ?? ""
    address.state = addressdictionary["State"] as? String ?? ""
    address.city = addressdictionary["City"] as? String ?? ""
    address.country = addressdictionary["Country"] as? String ?? ""
    address.postalCode = addressdictionary["ZIP"] as? String ?? ""

    return address
}

// Create a localized address string from an Address Dictionary
func localizedStringForAddressDictionary(addressDictionary: Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>) -> String {

    return CNPostalAddressFormatter.stringFromPostalAddress(postalAddressFromAddressDictionary(addressDictionary), style: .MailingAddress)
}
```

Comment: NB: This API is available from iOS9 upwards.

Comment: Thanks for this. FYI, the docs for `CNPostalAddressFormatter.stringFromPostalAddress` make no mention of the second `style` parameter but the build fails unless you have it. Take a look at the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNPostalAddressFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CNPostalAddressFormatter/stringFromPostalAddress:

Comment: Doesn't the use of "ZIP" make this specific to American addresses only?

Comment: The `addressDictionary` including the `ZIP` field is simply the format that the  geocoder returns the result in. ZIP is the name of the field, but the geocoder puts the equivalent value (like postal code) into this field where applicable as far as I'm aware. I don't live in America and it works for me.

Comment: `CNPostalAddressFormatter` doesn't seem to include delimiters in the string. For instance, there is no comma between city and state for an American address. Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 13):

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // get the address
    if let location = locations.last {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (result: [CLPlacemark]?, err: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let placemark = result?.last
                , addrList = placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String]
            {
                let address =  addrList.joinWithSeparator(", ")
                print(address)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Above is the swift version.

Comment: Apparently the subscripting of the addressDictionary does not work anymore in iOS 9

Comment: @FredA. I have updated the code to latest swift syntax.

Comment: As of Feb 3, 2017, swift is demanding an extra let in front of addrList and joinWithSeparator is now just joined.

Comment: why this takes two to three seconds for getting placemark

Answer (score 4):

**I am using Swift 3 / XCode 8**

[ZYiOS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29327953/6004931) was nice and short but did not compile for me.

The question asks how to get from an existing Address Dictionary to a string address. This is what I did:

```
import CoreLocation

func getAddressString(placemark: CLPlacemark) -> String? {
    var originAddress : String?

    if let addrList = placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String]
    {
        originAddress =  addrList.joined(separator: ", ")
    }

    return originAddress
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 / Xcode 8** Helper Mehtod to get address from CLPlaceMark

```
class func formattedAddress(fromPlacemark placemark: CLPlacemark) -> String{
    var address = ""

    if let name = placemark.addressDictionary?["Name"] as? String {
        address = constructAddressString(address, newString: name)
    }

    if let city = placemark.addressDictionary?["City"] as? String {
        address = constructAddressString(address, newString: city)
    }

    if let state = placemark.addressDictionary?["State"] as? String {
        address = constructAddressString(address, newString: state)
    }

    if let country = placemark.country{
      address = constructAddressString(address, newString: country)
    }

    return address
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Now this is as simple as

```
func updateUserAddress(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {[weak self] (placemarks, error) in
        if error == nil, let placemark = placemarks?.first, let address = placemark.postalAddress {
            self?.userLocationLabel.text = CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: address, style: .mailingAddress)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 11+

```swift
import CoreLocation
import Contacts

public extension CLPlacemark {
    func formattedAddress() -> String? {
        guard let postalAddress = postalAddress else { return nil }
        let formatter = CNPostalAddressFormatter()
        formatter.style = .mailingAddress
        let formatterString = formatter.string(from: postalAddress)
        return formatterString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create extension for `CLLocation`:

```
typealias AddressDictionaryHandler = ([String: Any]?) -> Void

extension CLLocation {

    func addressDictionary(completion: @escaping AddressDictionaryHandler) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self) { placemarks, _ in
            completion(placemarks?.first?.addressDictionary as? [String: AnyObject])
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let location = CLLocation()

location.addressDictionary { dictionary in

    let city = dictionary?["City"] as? String
    let street = dictionary?["Street"] as? String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 version**

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation!, preferredLocale: nil) { (clPlacemark: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in
            guard let place = clPlacemark?.first else {
                print("No placemark from Apple: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let addrList = place.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String] {
                let addressString = addrList.joined(separator: ", ")
                print(addressString)

            }
        }
```