# Contact address format for different countries

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

In an app, I am displaying the details of the contacts using ***ABRecordRef***. I am using the keys ***kABPersonAddressCityKey***, **kABPersonAddressStateKey**, **kABPersonAddressZIPKey**, **kABPersonAddressCountryKey**. Everything works fine. But I don't know in which format to display the addresses. What I mean is, if you see the ***Contacts app***, the addresses are displayed in a particular format for different countries. Some examples,

**US**

> Street
>   City State ZIP
>   Country

**India**

> Street
>   Province
>   City PIN
>   Country

**Australia**

> Street
>   Suburb State ZIP
>   Country

Now I don't know how to find the format for different countries.

1.Is there any way to find the address format based on country/country codes?
2.Is there a way we can get the fully formatted address using a single function, like we use **ABRecordCopyCompositeName()** to get the full name?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848291/how-to-get-formatted-address-nsstring-from-addressdictionary

Comment: Geez! Why you guys didn't tell me this before I offered a bounty?

Comment: because bounties are juicy O_O, and I haven't had seen your question. You know you could have typed exactly your question title and come across this? haha

Comment: Luis Oscar, ;-) I completely agree with you. Thanks man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this link 
[ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/Reference/reference.html)

It looks like you need to use: `ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary` that will return:

> Returns a formatted address from an address property. (From Apple)

Good luck

Comment: You are most welcomed, I just finished an addressbook app and I have to say that the AdreesBook docs are really crappy.

Answer (score 9):

From iOS 9.0 / macOS 10.11 / watchOS 2.0 on you should use [CNPostalAddressFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cnpostaladdressformatter) instead:

> The CNPostalAddressFormatter class formats the postal address in a contact. This class handles international formatting of postal addresses.

Below code is in Swift 3 but it is trivial to convert it to Objc

```
let postalAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
postalAddress.street = street
postalAddress.postalCode = zipCode
postalAddress.city = city
postalAddress.state = state
postalAddress.country = country
postalAddress.isoCountryCode = countryCode

let formattedAddress = CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: postalAddress, style: .mailingAddress)
```

Make sure you set the ISO country code property, this is used to determine the format of the address.

Example:

```
postalAddress.street = "Main Street 1"
postalAddress.postalCode = "67067"
postalAddress.city = "Ludwigshafen"
postalAddress.state = "Rhineland-Palatinate"
postalAddress.country = "Germany"
postalAddress.isoCountryCode = "DE"
```

leads to this

> Main Street 1
>
> 67067 Ludwigshafen
>
> Germany

whereas

```
postalAddress.isoCountryCode = "US"
```

leads to

> Main Street 1
>
> Ludwigshafen Rhineland-Palatinate 67067
>
> Germany