# CNContact: how to know which postal address properties to display for a given country?

Tags: ios, addressbook, cncontact, contactsui, cncontactformatter

The goal is to create a custom form for entering contact addresses.

If you edit a contact's properties with a `CNContactViewController` on iOS, the properties in a postal address change based on the country.

For instance, Afghanistan postal addresses don't show a postal code, but Argentina does. Hong Kong lists two fields for the street name.

Is there a way to programmatically know which properties of a postal address should be shown, given a certain country?

`CNPostalAddress` and `CNPostalAddressFormatter` don't seem to allow this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Contact address format for different countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134997/contact-address-format-for-different-countriesm)

Comment: @iOS thanks for the link, but those answers only explain how to format a string based on different countries. the goal is to know which fields to display to a user if you're creating a custom contact form.